# How to find out if store open or close - dealing with hours?

Tags: php, mysql, database

What is the best way to store shop opening and closing time in the database and also how to calculate the time in PHP?

I have come up with this table design:

```
+----+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| id | shop_id | week_day | open_hour | close_hour |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |       3 |        1 | 15:00:00  | 23:00:00   |
|  2 |       3 |        2 | 15:00:00  | 23:00:00   |
|  3 |       3 |        3 | 18:00:00  | 02:00:00   |
|  4 |       3 |        4 | 18:00:00  | 02:00:00   |
|  5 |       3 |        5 | 18:00:00  | 03:00:00   |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+------------+

+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| shop_id    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| week_day   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| open_hour  | time    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| close_hour | time    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

For example, on Tuesday (`week_day = 2`) it open at 3PM and close at 11PM (Tuesday).

On Wednesday (`week_day = 2'), it open at 6PM and close after midnight at 2AM which would be Thursday. How should midnight (00:00:00 or after) closing time should be stored in the database?

Let say customer want to place an order (`shop_id = 3`) at 10PM on Tuesday, they should be able to do so according to the database data. However if customer want to place an order at 1AM on Thursday but the database show that `week_day = 3` it close at `02:00:00`

How to write in PHP to work out if the shop open or not? it seem complicated!

Do I need to change the the table design so it would much easier to write in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider making the table information **truly correct**

```
+----+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| id | shop_id | week_day | open_hour | close_hour |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |       3 |        1 | 15:00:00  | 23:00:00   |
|  2 |       3 |        2 | 15:00:00  | 23:00:00   |
|  3 |       3 |        3 | 18:00:00  | 23:59:59   |
|  4 |       3 |        4 | 00:00:00  | 02:00:00   |
|  5 |       3 |        4 | 18:00:00  | 23:59:59   |
|  6 |       3 |        5 | 00:00:00  | 02:00:00   |
|  7 |       3 |        5 | 18:00:00  | 23:59:59   |
|  8 |       3 |        6 | 00:00:00  | 03:00:00   |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
```

Then use the following kind of (this query is for Tuesday 10:00PM as you mentioned):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `shop` 
 WHERE week_day=3 
 and open_hour<='22:00:00' 
 and close_hour>='22:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks for example, If shop open between 8PM to 12AM - should it be 20:00:00 to 23:59:59 ?

Comment: Good improvement to the strucutre. With this table structure, you could use a more dynamic SQL, like the one i suggested in my answer.

Comment: @user791022: Yes, according to this idea. Because, the calendar day advances at 00:00:00 in machines.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could do a SQL-question like this, and check if the query return any results:

```
SELECT * FROM opening_hours_table WHERE shop_id = your_shop_id AND week_day = WEEKDAY(NOW()) + 1 AND open_hour < NOW() AND close_hour > NOW()
```

If you get a result back, then your within opening hours.

**Edit:**
Made a few syntax-corrections to the SQL.

Comment: How should midnight or after midnight closing time should be stored?  see my example database result.

Comment: My bad, I wasn't reading good enough, just read the two first rows ending at 23.

Comment: @user791022 if you use a table like the one suggested in Sarwar's answer, i believe this query would work.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand (and correct me if I'm not understanding) you should check if the time is between the open_hour and 23:59 of the current day, and between 00:00 and close_hour of the following day.

That should be done on the APP code and not on the Database.

IMHO, you're right with your DB design!

Comment: Do you mean it should have second row if closing time after midnight? eg: if a shop open between 6pm to 2AM, so first row should 18:00 to 23:59 and then second row would be 00:00 to 02:00 .... ?