# Timespan - Check for weekday and time of day in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, time, timespan

I need to have a database with different rates at different time of day and on different weekdays.

For example:
`Between 10:00 and 16:00 monday to friday I have one rate. Between 16:00 and 10:00 monday to friday I have another. And on the weekends there is another rate.`

The problem is when the time goes over midnight.

I have looked around for a solution. I have found this thread that I thought would work for me but it doesn't. At least I can't get it to work as I want it to.
[Dealing with times and after midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278521/dealing-with-times-and-after-midnight/)

The other solution I tried didn't work either. It was to store time as TIME in mysql and check if the time and day was between the timespan in the database. This didn't work out either because I didn't find a good solution for when the timespan goes over midnight.

How should I try to solve this? What should the database look like and the query to get the data?

Edit:

Here is what it got so far. `starttid` = start time, `sluttid` = end time. `Ovrig_tid` is used when it's not any of the specific times. `startdag` = start day of week, `slutdag` = end day of week. 0 = monday, 6 = sunday. So the result should be max one from every `bolag_id`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT - Modified to meet criteria (end time) specified in comments:

I believe what you'll want to do is store each day's rate separately.  Store at least one value with the last minute of a given day as a final catch-all rate (this will be the only row for days with a single rate all day).  At any given day/time, just consult this table to determine the given rate for that period of time.  See below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tRate;
CREATE TABLE tRate (
    rateId         INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
    rateDay        TINYINT(1),
    rateEndTime  TIME,
    rate           DECIMAL(9,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (rateId)
)
;

INSERT INTO tRate VALUES
(NULL, 0, '00:10:00', '0.80'),
(NULL, 0, '23:59:59', '0.90'),
(NULL, 1, '00:10:00', '0.90'),
(NULL, 1, '00:16:00', '0.75'),
(NULL, 1, '23:59:59', '0.90')
-- (etc. for all days 0-6)
;

SET @execDay  = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%w');       -- 1 in the case of today for the resultset below
SET @execTime = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%m:%s'); -- 14:02:33 at the time this example was run
```

Given this data, the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    tRate
WHERE
    rateDay = @execDay
    and @execTime < rateEndTime
;
```

Returns the resultset for the particular execution time:

```
+--------+---------+-------------+------+
| rateId | rateDay | rateEndTime | rate |
+--------+---------+-------------+------+
|      5 |       1 | 23:59:59    | 0.90 |
+--------+---------+-------------+------+
```

Comment: Not really what I'm after. I need the end time so I can check if the time when the script is executed is between the time span and the right day of the week.

Comment: Modified my answer to hopefully better meet your needs.

Comment: Have added a picture now. Maybe it could give some understanding in what I want.

Comment: Probably worth noting that if you use my example (which I think suits your criteria nicely) I'd rename "rateEndTime" as "rateValidUntil" and  change the "< rateEndTime" condition to "<= rateValidUntil" to ensure that the minute of 23:59:59 is also properly handled.

Comment: I will check this out more tomorrow. Having a little trouble seeing how I should do to make it easy adding new rates. The optimal way and what I have right now is to add a start time, end time, start day, end day. The php script takes care of the rest. Can I do something similar with this? (It's probably easy. I'm just not thinking clearly right now :P )

Answer (score 1):

To make this really simple, you could have something like the following schema:

```
rate_by_hour
--------------------------------------
day     hour     rate
--------------------------------------
1       0        1.00
1       1        1.00
...
1       23       1.50
2       0        1.10
2       1        1.10
...
```

So, you have the rate separated by hour, for each day of the week.

Also, for each billable item, you have one row per hour:

```
charge_per_hour
----------------------------------------
user_id     date        hour   hour_used
----------------------------------------
1           2012/02/01  23      0.25
1           2012/02/02  0       1.00
1           2012/02/02  1       0.25
```

Here's the query to calculate the total:

```
SELECT SUM(c.hour_used * r.rate)
FROM charge_per_hour c
LEFT JOIN rate_by_hour r
ON r.day = DAYOFWEEK(c.date)
  AND r.hour = c.hour
WHERE user_id = 1
```